# Complex generics need some weird castings to run

Tags: c#, generics

Playing around with genericity, I built a simple social network model, base on persons and relations between them.

All of those are stored in a container.

For each container, I want to be able to add some validation to check some specific constraints.

Here is the maybe overly complex model, but as said, I'm playing with genericity, so it's kind of on purpose:

```
public interface IContainer<TPerson, TRelation>
    where TRelation : IRelation<TPerson>
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<TPerson> Persons { get; }
    IReadOnlyCollection<TRelation> Relations { get; }
}

public class DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>
    : IContainer<TPerson, TRelation>
    where TRelation : IRelation<TPerson>
{
    private readonly HashSet<TPerson> _persons;
    private readonly List<TRelation> _relations;

    //...
}

public class DummyValidator<TContainer, TPerson, TRelation>
    : IValidator<TContainer, TPerson, TRelation>
    where TContainer : IMutableContainer<TPerson, TRelation>
    where TRelation : IRelation<TPerson>
{
    public bool CanAddRelations(TContainer container, IEnumerable<TRelation> relations)
    {
        // guard clauses

        return true; // whatever
    }

    public bool CanCreate(IEnumerable<TPerson> persons, IEnumerable<TRelation> relations)
    {
        // guard clauses

        return CanAddRelations(new DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>(), relations);
    }

    //...
}

[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var sut = new DummyValidator<IContainer<int, IRelation<int>>, int, IRelation<int>>();
    sut.CanCreate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), Enumerable.Empty<IRelation<int>>());
}
```

Take a look at the `CanCreate` method of the `DummyValidator` class.
It creates a new container (implementing `TContainer`):

```
return CanAddRelations(new DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>(), relations);
```

So everything should be fine, as far as I can tell. But the compiler complains, saying:

> cannot convert from 'Alcuin.Graph.Containers.DefaultContainer' to 'TContainer'

My question is: why does it complain about that, even if every generic parameter is described and always equivalent ?

So I tried some explicit casts to investigate:

```
return CanAddRelations((TContainer)new DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>(), relations);
```

and

```
return CanAddRelations((IMutableContainer<TPerson, TRelation>)new DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>(), relations);
```

both fail, but:

```
return CanAddRelations((TContainer)(IMutableContainer<TPerson, TRelation>)new DefaultContainer<TPerson, TRelation>(), relations);
```

compiles and runs correctly...

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening here ?
Am I missing something obvious ? Am I reaching the limits of C#'s genericity engine ?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a smaller [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It seems that a substantial part of your question could be dropped from your question, do you agree?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I agree that it should be possible, I'm looking right now at what can be removed while preserving the behavior.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I removed a lot of stuff, is it better now ? I don't know if I can remove some more...

Comment: So I call `new DummyContainer<SomeOtherContainerType ....>().CanCreate(...)`. It turns around and creates a `DefaultContainer` and then tries to pass it to *this type*'s `CanAddRelations` method. But that's expecting a `SomeOtherContainerType`, not a `DefaultContainer`.

Comment: And once you're doing multiple casts, you're forcing the compiler to give up some of the type information that it has that is currently protecting you and it from a runtime error instead. (E.g. in my previous example, it would blow up at runtime saying it cannot cast a `DefaultContainer` to a `SomeOtherContainerType`)

Comment: (Sorry, the example should have been `DummyValidator` rather than `DummyContainer`, but hopefully you can see the problem).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Aah, that's what I missed. The compiler doesn't know whether the type I'll give at runtime will be in the inheritance tree of DefaultContainer or not. The fact that it runs in my case is just accidental, because the provided types are compatible... Thanks a lot, I'll need another coffee :)